# unable to pass input variables to terraform plan from github action

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have a github action entitled createVnet, this action takes inputs from a job called output_stuff. Output_stuff is sending the correct inputs to the job (createVnet) I can verify that by looking at the input task inside setup job (first step in the action for createVnet).

```
  createVNET:
uses: redacted/redacted/.github/workflows/plan.yml@main
with:
  ref: "main"
  AZURE_TENANT_ID: "redacted"
  AZURE_CLIENT_ID: "redacted"
  AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: "redacted"
  state_resource_group: "redacted"
  state_storageaccount: "redacted"
  state_container: "redacted"
  tgtrg: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.tgtrg}}
  tgtvnet: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.tgtvnet}}
  tgtlocation: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.tgtlocation}}
  tgtAddress: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.vnet}}
  tgtSubnet: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.subnet}}
  subnetName: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.name}}
  delegationName: ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.delegationName}}
  delegationAction : ${{needs.output_stuff.outputs.delegationAction}}
secrets: inherit
needs: output_stuff
```

the action.yml createvent is calling is below variables,

```
  workflow_call:
inputs:
  ref:
    type: string
    description: "The repository ref of the workflow to use."
  state_resource_group:
    type: string
    description: "The name of the resource group containing the Azure storage account defined in state_storageaccount."
    required: true
  state_storageaccount:
    type: string  
    description: "The Azure storage account used to store this workflows's terraform state."
    required: true
  state_container:
    type: string
    description: "The container in the Azure storage account used to store this workflows's terraform state."
    required: true
  tgtrg:
    type: string
    description: "The name of the resource group where the UDLR Will be built"
    required: true
  tgtlocation:
    type: string
    description: "The azure location where the udlr will be found"
    required: true
  tgtvnet:
    type: string
    description: "Name of the Virtual Network"
    required: true        
  tgtAddress:
    type: string
    description: "Root CIDR"
    required: true     
  tgtSubnet:
    type: string
    description: "Target Subnet"
    required: true        
  subnetName:
    type: string
    description: "Name of Subnet"
    required: true        
  delegationName:
    description: "is Delegation Needed?"
    type: string
    required: false 
  delegationAction:
    description: "whats Delecation Action"
    required: false     
    type: string 
  azure_client_id:
    type: string
    description: "Azure Client ID"
    required: true
  azure_tenant_id:
    type: string
    description: "Azure Tenant ID that contains the Client ID"
    required: true
  azure_subscription_id:
    type: string
    description: "Azure Subscription ID"
    required: true
  tags:
    type: string
    description: "Comma delimited list of tags.  Tags must be in the form of key|value."
    required: false
  tf_debug:
    type: boolean
    description: "Enable terraform debug logging."
    default: true
    required: false
secrets:
  application_id:
    description: "The GitHub Application ID used to authenticate to checkout this private action"
    required: true
  application_private_key:
    description: "The private key for the given GitHub Application ID"
    required: true
```

I'm also converting the inputs to an environment variable inside github using this,

```
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
    node-version: '20'
- uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v3

- name: Check for the target resource group
  if: "${{ inputs.tgtrg != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_tgtrg=${{ inputs.tgtrg }}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

- name: Check for the target resource group location
  if: "${{ inputs.tgtlocation  != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_tgtlocation=${{ inputs.tgtlocation }}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

- name: Check for the target vnet name
  if: "${{ inputs.tgtvnet  != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_tgtvnet=${{ inputs.tgtvnet }}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"    

- name: Check for the target subnet 
  if: "${{ inputs.tgtAddress != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_tgtAddress=${{ inputs.tgtAddress }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Check for the target subnet name
  if: "${{ inputs.subnetName != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_subnetName=${{ inputs.subnetName }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Check for the target subnet 
  if: "${{ inputs.delegationName != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_delegationName=${{ inputs.delegationName }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Check for the target subnet name
  if: "${{ inputs.delegationAction != '' }}"
  shell: bash
  run: echo "TF_VAR_delegationAction=${{ inputs.delegationAction }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

lastly, under the plan im using the below flag to ignore inputs from users,

```
    - name: Terraform Plan
  id: plan
  shell: bash
  env:
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ inputs.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
    ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ inputs.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ inputs.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  run: terraform -chdir=${{ inputs.state_container }} plan -no-color -input=false
```

**The Problem**

When we arrive at the createVnet action I see "Convert Inputs to Environments variables" step echoing the correct variables for each of the tf_vars defined above. It then progresses through the plan erroring out at terrafrom plan. The error I am getting implies it can't find the tf_vars variable I know was stitched together in a previous step. This is erroring out on every variable I have defined minus azure client / tenant / subscription / and all state stuff. Here's error I'm getting,

> Error: No value for required variable
>
> on main.tf line 69:   69: variable "delegationName" {
>
> The root module input variable "delegationName" is not set, and has no
> default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to
> provide a value for this variable.
>
> Error: No value for required variable
>
> on main.tf line 73:   73: variable "delegationAction" {
>
> The root module input variable "delegationAction" is not set, and has
> no default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to
> provide a value for this variable.

My main.tf is pretty basic here's one of the input variables I have defined. the only difference between my variables in main. some of them are list(strings) don't really think my main.tf is the problem though but figured I'd post it just in case.

```
variable "tgtvnet" {
  description = "Name of the Virtual Network"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could it be the `$GITHUB_ENV` acting up?  ... before the tf plan command, can you output the env vars see if everything is in there

Comment: I also recommend you to create a repo with minimal code showing your issue, that will make it very easy to reproduce your problem

Comment: It's difficult to say since we can't see the full workflow file, but I suspect you're environment variables are out of scope when you reach the problem step. Are all of these steps in the same job?

Answer (score 0):

Making a best guess based on on what's been provided. You're attempting to use the environment variables after they go out of scope. [You cannot access environment variables set through workflow expression in a different job in the same workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).